# Problem with cv2 : C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:627: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to test out the **cv2** library in a virtual environment in Anaconda terminal, I'm doing some object detection coding and when I execute I have this error `

> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:627:
>   error: (-2: Unspecified error) The function is not implemented.`

Comment: Do you have a question? Maybe you're running some code that's causing this error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm trying object detection with tensorflow and the python code imports cv2 so i can do the imread and imshow

Comment: Unfortunately, this still is not neither a question, nor a problem description. Please provide a [mcve].